$f(x)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_ne^{inx}$ $\mathbb{R}$-analytic

Let $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complex numbers such that for some $C \in ]0,\infty[$:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}: |a_n| \leq Ce^{-n}$$
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$ be defined as:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_ne^{inx}$$
$f$ is infinitely differentiable:
$$
\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{f_n}^{´}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}ina_ne^{inx} 
$$
$$
|in a_n e^{inx}|=n|a_n| \leq Ce^{-n}n
$$
And as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Ce^{-n}n$ converges, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{f_n}^{´}(x)$ converges uniformly by M-Weierstrass Test and $f'(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{f_n}^{´}(x)$.
By induction, $f_n^{(k)}(x)=i^kn^ka_ne^{inx}; k \in \mathbb{N}$ and $f$ is infinitely differentiable.
Now we have:
\begin{align*}
&Re(f(x)) \\[9 pt]
=&\frac{f(x)+\overline{f(x)}}{2} \\
=&\frac{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_ne^{inx}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\overline{a_n}e^{-inx}}{2} \\[9 pt]
=&\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Re(a_n)\cos(nx)-\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}Im(a_n)\sin(nx)
\end{align*}
And analogous for $Im(f(x))$; how can I argue that both $Re(f(x)); Im(f(x))$ are analytic?

The function is (complex) analytic on ${  z\in \mathbb{C} \ : \ \text{Im}(z) \in (-1/2,1/2) }$ as we have normal convergence.

Check for what $z \in \mathbb{C}$ is the derivative series $\sum_{n =  1}^{\infty}i n a_n e^{inz}$ is absolutely convergent. Then use dominated convergence to prove that the complex derivative of $f(z)$ will be this series in that region.
